# How to bind BeanItemContainer to Combobox

Tags: spring, combobox, vaadin7

I have BeanItemContainer, which i load from database via jdbc:

```
BeanItemContainer myBeans = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class, mybeanDao.findAll());
```

and this is how i attach it to combobox:

```
Combobox combo = new Combobox();
combobox.setContainerDataSource(myBeans);
```

So far, so good. I received what i want, but for now i have a problem - 
How do i get actual id that has been selected? This must be synchronized (id selected in combobox is actual entry in database).

I have no idea, how to solve this problem

Please help

P.S MyBean class

```
public class MyBean {

    private Long id;
    private String field1;

*** getters /setters ***
  and toString() {} method 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Here is the code:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    setContent(layout);

    BeanItemContainer myBeans = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class, getBeans());

    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.setContainerDataSource(myBeans);
    combo.setItemCaptionMode(AbstractSelect.ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
    combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("field");

    combo.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
            MyBean bean = (MyBean) combo.getValue();

            Notification notif = new Notification("Selected Bean Id: "+bean.getId(), Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
            notif.setPosition(Position.TOP_CENTER);
            notif.show(Page.getCurrent());
        }
    });

    layout.addComponent(combo);
}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

public class MyBean {

    private Long id;
    private String field;

    public MyBean(Long id, String field) {
        this.id = id;
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

}

public ArrayList<MyBean> getBeans() {
    ArrayList<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();

    MyBean bean = new MyBean(1l, "Vikrant");
    beans.add(bean);

    bean = new MyBean(2l, "Rampal");
    beans.add(bean);

    bean = new MyBean(3l, "viky");
    beans.add(bean);


    return beans;
}
```

}

Comment: I've tested your option and it worked good. But there's a problem. You see i have vaadin spring application and this suppose to attach this beanItemContainer to modal window. So i need to preload beans from database when user navigates to modal window.I tried to use @PostConstruct but it did nothing (or i made smth wrong). Big thanks

Comment: I do not see any issues in your approach. It should work. Probably you can share some code.

Comment: Unfortunately , i can't make code atm, but i will let you know when it's done. Please stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly combo.getValue() should give you the MyBean instance relative to the current selection (or null if no item is selected)

Comment: yes, you understood my problem correctly. however 'combo.getValue()' returns 'Object' object, which is kinda hard to convert to Long problematic. But once it's done i have some problems with a data persistence - 1) it writes to database caption of selected item or... (i tried to convert to Long using tresspass as toString) whole line(with id and other related stuff)